# Math Calculation - float numbers

Tags: c++

I am doing the following

```
float years = (1/31536000) * 883102.00;
```

and I get years = 0000000

while the actual answer is 0.0.28

Any suggestion on what might be going wrong ?

Comment: try to add the `f` suffix on each and every number

Comment: @user2485710 `1f` is not valid C++.

Comment: @PascalCuoq ok I mean `1.0f`, add `.0f` to each number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should instead do

```
float years = (1.0/31536000.0) * 883102.00;
```

or

```
float years = (1.0/31536000) * 883102.00;
```

might work as well. Your very first number is treated as integer.

Comment: Did the trick -Thanks

Comment: I personally prefer `(1.f / 31536000)`

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
float years = 883102.00/31536000;
```

This will save computation.
Since you are diving 1 by something and then multiplying.
Alternatively just set 1 to 1.00

Answer (score 1):

1 is an int.  The compiler then assumes that you are interested in working in ints and then 1/3153600 becomes 0.  Just add a .0 to the 1 and your calc should work.

```
float years = (1.0/31536000) * 883102.00;
```

Answer (score 1):

That first term is being cast as an `int`, and thus is being rounded to `0`. Try this:

```
float years = (1.00 / 31536000.00) * 883102.00
```

Comment: Why only two zeroes after the decimal point? Shouldn’t you add a few more to be safe?

Comment: There is no cast here. The first term has type `int` and the second term has type `int`, so their quotient has type `int`. The value is **truncated**, not rounded.

Comment: @PeteBecker: “Rounding” is used to mean modification of a result to fit within a destination format (e.g., IEEE 754-2008 4.3), and various modes of rounding can be used, such as rounding toward zero.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - the answer doesn't "rounds toward 0", it just says that the result is "rounded". That is, at best, sloppy terminology. The C++ language definition says that integer division truncates. (Formally, it discards the fractional part).

Answer (score 1):

(1/31536000) will yield 0 that multiplied by any number would be 0.
Make atleast one of numerator or denominator float (like 1.0 or 31536000.0)

Answer (score 1):

`883102.0 / 31536000` will do just what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the Integer-Division

```
(1/31536000)
```

the fractional digits get truncate and the result is "zero".
You have to add a dot:

```
(1.0/31536000.0) or (1./31536000.)
```